# Run custom Python script before appcfg.py update runs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment

Is that possible to run some Python script every time I run deployment process with appcfg.py? I need that to copy some files from external source to my app folder before uploading it to GAE. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running script on server start in google app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252672/running-script-on-server-start-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question, @systempuntoout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked briefly the sources of `appcfg.py`, the script that deploys the application to Google App Engine, but I didn't find a place where a pre-deploy hook can be defined.

I believe that modifying `appcfg.py` itself would me not mantainable and a bit overkill.

You should create a simple deployment script and call your command from the script.

For example, you can create a simple `Makefile` with only one target that does what you want:

```
deploy:
    your-copy-command
    /path/to/gae-devkit/appcfg.py update .
```

Running the `make` command will execute the command to copy external files and call the Google App Engine deployment tool.